# Access props of react component in separate file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two react components that have to stay in separate files but need to share a property. One component will change the `this.props.color` and the other component needs to know what that new color is. I know you can import the actual component but I don't know how to access the properties from that component. Here's a very simple example of my app (I'm using ES6)

component1.js

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class FirstComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    color: PropTypes.string
  }
  handleClick () {
    //change color here
  }
  render () {
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor: this.props.color
    };
    return <div id="one" style={styles} onclick={this.handleClick}></div>;
  }
}
```

component2.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import FirstComponent from './component1.js';

export default class SecondComponent extends Component {
  /*...*/
  render () {
    console.log(FirstComponent); //??
    return <div id="two"></div>;
  }
}
```

parent1.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import FirstComponent from './component1.js';

export default class FirstComponentParent extends Component {
  color = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
  return React.createElement(FirstComponent, {color: this.color});
}
```

parent2.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SecondComponent from './component2.js';

export default class SecondComponentParent extends Component {
  return React.createElement(SecondComponent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a common parent component and pass the color as a prop to the second component and pass a method updating the color as a prop to the first component.

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class FirstComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {color: 'black'};
  }
  handleClick () {
    //change color here
    this.props.changeColor(newColor);
  }
  render () {
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor: this.state.color
    };
    return <div id="one" style={styles} onclick={this.handleClick}></div>;
  }
}
```

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class SecondComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor: this.props.color
    };
    return <div id="one" style={styles}></div>;
  }
}
```

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import FirstComponent from './first';
import SecondComponent from './second';

export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {firstColor: 'black'};
  }
  changeColor = (newColor) => {
    this.setState({firstColor: newColor});
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <FirstComponent changeColor={this.changeColor}/>
        <SecondComponent color={this.state.firstColor}/>
      </div>;
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: i had done this previously but the components have to be in separate parent components because there are other things happening that are important in those files. i didn't include that extra code because i just made a minimal example

Comment: In that case if you are using a flux pattern setup an app.store and use an action rather than the parent method. I attach the app.store to my highest component and pass appstate as a prop.